# Angular generated filenames too long

Tags: angular-cli

I'm building an Angular 10 enterprise app. When building with --prod we generate extremely long filenames containing tildes, such as

```
default~device-overview-device-overview-module~group-overview-group-overview-module~rule-overview-ru~1e39f90e.a0c2aafc27b60aa57fc0.js
```

This messes up our deployment system. Is there a way to get Angular to use shorter filenames?

(I'm not concerned about the cache-busting hashes - I need those).

Comment: Please post the full `ng build` command you are using. Also, please include the `build` and `cli` full values from your `angular.json` file

Answer (score 0):

Check the `angular.json` file, which configures the build process.

You can use the output hashing to configure the desired filename.

```
"production": {
  "outputHashing": "...",
  ...
}
```

- e.g. `"media"`, will just give them incremental numbers, and results in the shortest names.
- e.g. `"all"` will give each file a unique hash code based on their content.
- e.g. You can also put it on `"none"` if you want them unmodified.

Alternatively, you can also enforce this from the CLI, but it's more convenient to just configure it once.